# How to export Angular HTML template with Angular function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, dynamically-generated

I want to create a angular form generator. I have template like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="textarea.html">
    <div class="items form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            {{item.title}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea ng-model="task.title" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and when user add this template that generate Angular html code like this:

```
    <div class="items form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            {{item.title}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea ng-model="task.title" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With this example my template code rendered but I don't want render it and just show angular html code. If you have any suggestion, please change this code.

**[Example Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ImqWj65YllaCYD5kX5E?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-bind instead of ng-include;

example:

```
**in app.js.**

app.run(['$injector', function($injector) {
  var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

  rootScope.tpl = '<h1 style="color:green;">This is the page content</h1>';
}])

**in index.js**

<span ng-bind='tpl'></span>
```

Comment: How to assign template to `$injector`. I have many template that include with name of this and can't put in `app.run(....)`.

Comment: you can use $templateCache service to obtain template which is the content of script directive

Answer (score 0):

If you use normal tags it will render but if you don't want to render it then you can use

```
replace < by &lt; and > by &gt;
```